# jQuery I can get val but id is undefined?

Tags: jquery

I am missing something I think... I need the value and id of a datepicker input that is in each row of a table. This code loops and searches but is not working as I expected. The table contains rows like this

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" id="pd_abc_123" class="datePicker"></td>
 <td><input type ="checkbox" id="blahblah"></td>
</tr>

$(table).find("tbody>tr").not(':first').each(function () {
                    var datePicker = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
                    var dt = $(datePicker).val();
                    alert(dt);
                    alert($(datepicker).id);
                    alert($(datepicker).attr("id"));
                });
```

Also I tried to find the input via class but it also comes back undefined

```
var temp = $(this).find(".datePicker");
```

Comment: `datePicker` is already a jQuery object. Why are you wrapping it again?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, missing `)` for the last alert.

Comment: I fixed the syntax error but that is not the issue... I am still getting undefined with both datePicker.id and $(datePicker).attr("id");

Comment: You defined `datePicker` but try to use `datepicker`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").find("tbody>tr").not(':first').each(function () {
    var datePicker = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
    var dt = datePicker.val();
    alert(dt);                    // value
    alert(datePicker.attr("id")); // ID
});
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/jNZg6/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code:

1. In your alert `datepicker` had a lowercase `p`
2. Missing semi-colon after the second alert.

Also don't forget to close `<input>` tags with `/>`

Fixed example:

```
$('table').find("tbody>tr").not(':first').each(function () {
    var datePicker = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
    var dt = datePicker.val();
    alert(dt);
    alert(datePicker.attr("id"));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c5bjd/2/

You can figure out these errors using your [browser developer tools](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/147/checking-for-errors-in-browsers/page-1).